# compact java.util.Map implementation

Tags: java, dictionary

Is there any java.util.Map implementation that do not stores Values of equals ValueObjects but store only one of them? (references of this Objects are different, but they are equals)

here is a little test code :

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(); 
for (int i = 0; i <= 1000000; i++) { 
map.put(i, new Integer(42)); 
}
```

and visual VM shows :
2 million of instances of Integer
these objects are equals
but Map stores all of them

[image]

Just for history logging I coded chiastic-security's solution and test it to compare with HashMap:

```
public class CompactMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V> {

private Map<K, V> map;
private Map<V, V> canonicalMap;

public CompactMap() {
    map = new HashMap<K, V>();
    canonicalMap = new HashMap<V, V>();
}

@Override
public void clear() {
    map.clear();
    canonicalMap.clear();
}

@Override
public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
    return map.containsKey(key);
}

@Override
public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
    return map.containsValue(value);
}

@Override
public Set<java.util.Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
    return map.entrySet();
}

@Override
public V get(Object key) {
    return map.get(key);
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return map.isEmpty();
}

@Override
public Set<K> keySet() {
    return map.keySet();
}

@Override
public V put(K key, V value) {
    V canonValue = canonicalMap.get(value);
    V previous = null;
    if (canonValue != null) {
        previous = map.put(key, canonValue);
    } else {
        previous = map.put(key, value);
        canonicalMap.put(value, value);
    }
    return previous;
}

@Override
public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
    if (m == null) throw new NullPointerException("Can't exceute putAll for null-map argument");
    for (Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V> entry : m.entrySet()) {
        map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
}

@Override
public V remove(Object key) {
    V removalValue = map.get(key);
    map.remove(key);
    if (!map.containsValue(removalValue)) {
        canonicalMap.remove(removalValue);
    }
    return removalValue;
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return map.size();
}

@Override
public Collection<V> values() {
    return map.values();
}

}
```

test compact map:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Map<Integer, Integer> compactMap = new CompactMap<Integer, Integer>();
       //Map<Integer, Integer> usualMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
       for (int i=0; i<=1000000; i++) {
           compactMap.put(i, new Integer(i % 1000));
           // usualMap.put(i, new Integer(i % 1000));
       }
    }
```

VisualVM heap dump for CompactMap:
[image]

test HashMap :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       // Map<Integer, Integer> compactMap = new CompactMap<Integer, Integer>();
       Map<Integer, Integer> usualMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
       for (int i=0; i<=1000000; i++) {
           // compactMap.put(i, new Integer(i % 1000));
           usualMap.put(i, new Integer(i % 1000));
       }
    }
```

VisualVM heap dump for HashMap:
[image]

Comment: A `BiMap`? There is an implementation in Guava.

Comment: Is it possible in BiMap : multiple Keys references to a single value ?

Comment: How would that work? Just use a normal `Map`. Put the same mapping in multiple times.

Comment: HashMap will store every new ValueObject as a new object (even if they are equals) and waste the memory

Comment: I don't think your understand how Java works.

Comment: I'll show you a simple example in a few minutes with a Java VisualVM explanation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66857/discussion-between-user2602807-and-boris-the-spider).

Comment: This seems like a perfectly good question to me, and quite a reasonable requirement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard implementations don't handle this, but you could roll your own easily enough. The trick is to keep hold of a `HashMap<K,V> map` to hold your real mappings, and another `HashMap<V,V> canonical` to make sure your values don't end up containing two equal but non-identical references.

Whenever you want to add something to your `map` with `map.put(key,value)`, you should

1. Look up `value` in your `canonical` map to see whether you've encountered something equal to this before. If `canonical.get(value)` returns something, then this is the canonical representation you should put into `map`.
2. If it doesn't exist in `canonical`, then call `map.put(key,value)` to add it to the main map, and also `canonical.put(value,value)` so that you now have a canonical representation for things equal to this value.

Comment: Why a `HashMap` for `canonical`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I guess a `HashMap<V, V>` where you can look up the pooled instance and hope the instance you used to get the pooled instance is gc'd.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis because it does exactly the right thing. It efficiently stores a reference indexed by its hash code. It gives you an O(1) way of finding your canonical representation. But if there's something better then I'm happy to have this improved upon!

Comment: This is a nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are confused to the meanings of equality in Java. When you call new, a new instance will always be created. It is not trivial to determine if it is "equal" to another one, as it might have several fields of several complex types.

If you do something like this instead:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(); 
Integer answer = new Integer(42);
for (int i = 0; i <= 1000000; i++) { 
    map.put(i, answer); 
}
```

Then only one instance is created. The would only point to one place in memory, that, if altered, would change everyone (though Integer and every other wrapper are immutable in Java, meaning the cannot change).

Comment: No, I am not confused to the meanings of equality in Java.